# How to add assets in flutter Package/Plugin development?

Tags: flutter, dart, assets, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I am developing a flutter package containing some assets files. I mentioned required assets in pubsepc.yaml as usual like this

```
  assets:
    - assets/abc.xyz
```

and uploaded the package to https://pub.dartlang.org/.

After that I created a flutter Application and imported my developed package in `pubspec.yaml` like...

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  my_developed_package: ^0.0.1
```

Now everything is working fine except my assets are absent.
I put some assets in my Application without mentioning in `pubsepc.yaml` and its working. I am unable to understand, how do I add these assets to my package so that they load automatically?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following approach helped me for including assets (not only images but any type of file) in plugin development.

I put my assets under the `lib` folder like, `my_plugin/lib/assets` and in `pubspec.yaml` like this.

```
  assets:
    - packages/my_plugin/assets/asset_name
       
  # Be careful about indentation
```

> It is mandatory to put your plugin assets in the lib directory, in other
> directories it won't work.

It has been added with the plugin and then I accessed them with a path like this
`packages/my_plugin/assets/asset_name`, e.g.

```
File myAsset = File("packages/my_plugin/assets/asset_name");
```

By this approach, I was able to get an asset from Plugin not only Images.

For a complete example, you can check my plugin [here](https://github.com/shah-xad/flutter_tex).

Comment: This is a winner, thank you!  I spent all morning trying to get my package to load it's own JSON file, and found the flutter documentation a little.....unclear.

Comment: I want to read json file from plugin assets can you help me out ?

Comment: This works but I have to include every single asset file separately in the application's `pubspec.yaml` under `assets:`. Is there any way to include all assets under a package folder too like one can do for normal assets in an application?

Comment: Thanks for that! I can confirm that this works. I specified the txt file in the pubspec.yaml` of the package project and accessed it via `rootBundle.loadString('packages/package_name/file.txt)`. Note that the file is in `package_name/lib/file.txt`.  No need to specify the `lib` folder

Comment: @GoingBananas Have you found any way to add a folder instead of adding each and every file in pubspec yaml

Comment: @RevanthKrishnaKumarV., yes I have. In my most recent Flutter projects I am putting images and any other media type files in an assets folder under the lib project's root folder. Then, in lib project's `pubspec.yaml` I add `flutter:\n  assets:\n    - assets/` (Note the backslash at the end. It is necessary). Then, in other projects `pubspec.yaml` that have dependency on lib project, I add: `dependencies:\n  project_lib:\n    path: ../project_lib` (although you might fetch your dependency lib project from a registry if you have one setup.

Comment: @RevanthKrishnaKumarV. See https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images#from-packages

Answer (score 23):

Quote [from](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#bundling-of-package-assets)

> If the desired asset is specified in the pubspec.yaml file of the
>   package, it is bundled automatically with the application. In
>   particular, assets used by the package itself must be specified in its
>   pubspec.yaml.

In Flutter you can use assets from packages, it should not be a problem. Only thing is, you need to specify your package and import it. E.g. If it's an image, you can use `AssetImage` class and it's `package` attribute.

```
AssetImage('assets/abc.xyz', package: 'my_developed_package');
```

For more information about how you can call texts and other stuff, please check [here](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-images-in-package-dependencies).

Comment: I got this point but I want them to automatically add when someone installs my plugin. how to accomplish that?

Comment: If you see the quoted information in the edited answer, you can see that, package assets automatically bundled to the application.

Comment: Only AssetImage allows you to specify a package.  If you want to load a json file it doesn't work, and I find the documentation very difficult to understand on this. It states you can have assets not defined in the pubspec.yaml, but in the next sentence still says you have to define them in the pubspec.yaml.

Comment: @eimmer - you can have several assets and you can specify some but not necessarily all of them to be available for users of the package. The rest will be for your package's own use but not exposed to the outside world.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Have been looking for hours. Only if I can choose this is as the best answer because the answer below is a bit arduous task to achieve same thing.

Comment: Thank you! Should be marked as an only correct answer. I spent a couple hours trying to figure out why assets cannot be loaded, until I found your reply about this `package` parameter. In my case, I use a flutter_svg+fluttergen, it looks like this: `Assets.icons.lock.svg(package: 'granat')`

Answer (score 1):

If you are, as I am, refactoring large amounts of code into a library, and you need your images to be part of that library, as well as reference those images from within that library, you can sort of follow the instructions in the [Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images#specifying-assets)

Here is my working example.  **Package** pubspec.yaml:

```
assets:
  - lib/assets/
  - lib/assets/images/
```

Example reference **within package**:

```
Image.asset("packages/my_library/assets/images/my_image.png")
```

**Package** directory structure:

```
└── my_library
    ├── lib
    │   ├── assets
    │   │   ├── my_noise.mp3
    │   │   └── images
    │   │       └── my_image.png
    │   └── library_code
    └── pubspec.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Assets to a Flutter Package can get Difficult!
Just follow these steps and you're good to go...

Step 1: Make an **assets** folder in the root directory of the Package

Step 2: Add it to your **pubspec.yaml** file

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/asset_name

# Mind the indentation
```

Step 3: Using the **asset**, for an image file

```
AssetImage('assets/asset_name.png', package: 'your_package_name')
```

Run **Pub.dev** and do a **Cold Start** for the Flutter Application using the Package and

## Voila You're Done.

Comment: How would one load non-image assets from a package? e.g. .json or .dat file?

Answer (score -3):

**Pubspec yaml is indentation  sensitive**

there is a difference between

```
 assets:
  - packages/my_plugin/assets/asset_name
```

***VS***

```
 assets:
   - packages/my_plugin/assets/asset_name
```

If you closely notice at above two then you will find that pubspec.yaml is very sensitive

always write

```
assets:
  -asset/yourasset/example1
```

**there must be two spaces from the beginning of line.**

After adding asset link to pubspec you have to run **packages get**  It will show exits with 0 error if you place your assets properly otherwise it will show you reason behind the error.

Generally, Beginners face these type of problems. With time you will crack the way to solve this error