# Flutter - Asset images in package dependencies

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-assetimage

We have the following structure:
**Package A is a flutter app, It has it's assets folder and is loading assets like this: Image.asset("assets/images/background.png"). project B, that uses package A as dependency.**

When I run **package A** from **Project B**, some widget of package A have image can not show. **Error:** `Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/images/light_theme_background.svg`

When I added the "package" field to the **AssetImage** in the **package A**, Error is fixed when I run package A from project B, however the **package A** couldn't read its own contents.

```
const AssetImage('assets/heart.png', package: 'my_packages');
```

> Is there a way to package A when it can read assets on run from itself and run from the project that takes it as a dependency?

**Error when run package A:** *"Another exception was thrown: Unable to load assets: `package/my_packages/assets/images/background.png`"*

In the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images#from-packages) it says: **"Content used by the package itself should also be fetched using the package argument as above."**

I tried copying ***assets*** folder to ***lib*** folder and also declaring in ***pubspec.yaml*** file like the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740732/how-to-add-assets-in-flutter-package-plugin-development). However, most reported "Bad state: Invalid SVG data " and "Exception: Invalid image data" errors even though they are all normal.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I might have a solution using [flutter_gen package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gen).
I managed to strip it down to not having this structure in the pubspec.yaml file of the dependency package, in your case package A:

```
flutter_gen:
  assets:
    outputs:
      package_parameter_enabled: true
```

After adding this I was able to see my pdf file. [that was my use case]