# Flutter: Can I access asset folder in custom plugin development?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I am developing a Flutter plugin and I want to access the files which are in my plugin folder, not in my demo example folder.
Here is my project structure:

```
assets/
  myfile.txt (what I want to access)
example/
  lib/
    main.dart (where I execute my demo app & import my plugin)
lib/src/
  plugin.dart (where I export my plugin library)
  getfile.dart (where I want to access 'assets/myfile.txt')
android/
ios/
```

I'd like to access `assets/myfile.txt`, I hope this will be referenced by the plugin code and later to be used in demo app.

I tried using functions in `package:path_provider/path_provider.dart` like `getApplicationSupportDirectory()`, `getTemporaryDirectory()`, and `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`. They all direct me to `/data/user/0/com.mycompany.dartplugin_example/...` folder, which is my demo app folder.

I also tried `rootBundle.load()` but it directs me to `example/assets/myfile.txt`, that is not what I expect, either.

Can I access the directory & files of my custom plugin in my demo app?

If anyone knows the answer I would really appreciate it!

**Update:**

The [2019 Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740732/how-to-add-assets-in-flutter-package-plugin-development) solved the issue if we specify every asset file name in pubspec.yaml. And the assets should be put under the lib/ folder. However, there is a question (by Going Bananas) unsolved:

> This works but I have to include every single asset file separately in the application's pubspec.yaml under assets:. Is there any way to include all assets under a package folder too like one can do for normal assets in an application?

Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: Did you find anything on this, or are we relegated to individually listing the assets?